# Makefile not executing, error expects symbol

Tags: c, makefile

Just have been trying to write a makefile that consists of 5 files --> arrays.h
arrays.c pointers.h pointers.c stringtest.c

When I run make however, I get and error expecting "=", "," ";" etc and it then later says that no targets are specified. Any ideas?

```
stringtest : stringtest.c arrays.o pointers.o
    cc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -Werror -o stringtest stringtest.c arrays.o pointers.o 

arrays.o : arrays.c arrays.h
    cc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -Werror -c -o arrays.o arrays.c

pointers.o : pointers.c pointers.h
    cc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -Werror -c -o pointers.o pointers.c
```

Comment: Use more variables in your `Makefile`

Comment: Are you using tabs in the right places?

Comment: Please show us the exact error message. *expect[ed] "=", "," ";"* looks more like something that would come from the C compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using TABs for indentation?
Commands for an target must be indent with it. Like:

```
pointers.o: ...
---->cc -std=c99 ..
```